# controller@store not defined error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I installed laravelcollective and am trying to run the following code

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProductController@store','method' => 'POST']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('title','Title')}}
        {{Form::text('title',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title'])}}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I get this error

```
App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@store not defined. (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lsapp/resources/views/product/create.blade.php)
```

When I run php artisan route:list I see:

```
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/user               |                  | Closure              | api,auth:api |
|        | POST      | events                 | events.store     | App\Http\Controllers\eventcontroller@store              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | events                 | events.index     | App\Http\Controllers\eventcontroller@index              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | events/create          | events.create    | App\Http\Controllers\eventcontroller@create              | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | events/{event}         | events.update    | App\Http\Controllers\eventcontroller@update              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | events/{event}         | events.show      | App\Http\Controllers\eventcontroller@show              | web          |
|        | DELETE    | events/{event}         | events.destroy   | App\Http\Controllers\eventcontroller@destroy              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | events/{event}/edit    | events.edit      | App\Http\Controllers\eventcontroller@edit              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                   | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index              | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login              | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm              | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout              | web          |
|        | POST      | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | password/reset         |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset              | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register              | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistra
```

Comment: Have you created ProductController and in that store method ?

Comment: Can you post your routes file too

Comment: @Option done I added routes

Comment: @Pratik yes i have added routes

Comment: @joem where is the ProductController related routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the best practice and to have maintained code I wish to follow my advice :

1) go to routes/web.php and add name to your `ProductController@store` method like this :

```
Route::post('','ProductController@store')->name('products.store');
```

2) go to you `create.blade.php` file and change it like this :

```
{!! Form::open(array( 'route'=>'products.store')) !!} 
    <div class="form-group">    
    {{Form::label('title','Title')}}  
    {{Form::text('title',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title'])}} 
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: He did not use a route? https://youtu.be/-QapNzUE4V0?t=4m58s????

Comment: to use both of route or action is the same thing

Comment: I have added route list above

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Laravel Collective form with action, you do not declare the method as the second parameter, that's only if you declare a url, you use that as route parameters, usually to add in an ID if one is needed in the url. First, try and remove the `'method' => 'POST'` section and see if that works.

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: He did not use a route? https://youtu.be/-QapNzUE4V0?t=4m58s ??

Comment: You can check the documentation for Laravel Collective here to show that you don't need it. https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a resource controller or a single route in your routes/web.php file?

You have couple of options here:

For your Form::open, you can use either *Action, Route or URL*

**Action:**

```
   {!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProductController@store']) !!}
    // By default, a POST method will be assumed 
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('title','Title')}}
            {{Form::text('title',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title'])}}
        </div>
    // If you use the Form::open method with POST, PUT or DELETE the CSRF token will be added to your forms as a hidden field automatically.
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Route:**

First name your route in your routes/web.php file:

```
Route::post('/productURL', 'ProductController@store')->name('productRouteName');
```

Then open the form:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'productRouteName'] !!}
```

**URL:**

Just call the url from the route you created above..

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'productURL'] !!}
```

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: He did not use a route? https://youtu.be/-QapNzUE4V0?t=4m58s

Comment: He has created a resource controller, most likely by using "php artisan make:controller ProductController --resource" in a terminal.   You can check if you have this by viewing your routes by using "php artisan route:list".

Comment: So you have not created your Product route yet?  If you havent already, run the make:controller command in my comment above, and then add "Route::resource('product','ProductController');" to your routes/web.php file.

Comment: Also, I see you have created an EventController already.   Whilst you are learning, its a good idea to follow the coding conventions and use CamelCase to name your controllers.

Comment: Hello, I have added that, It seems that just @update isnt working ? all the other routes in the controller are

Comment: Great, glad to hear that all is working.   Do you want to put your update function problem up in a new question?

Comment: Hi, @joe-m, can you pick an answer and close this question please?